# Remove first and last character of string only if they match in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

So I'm basically reading the first line from a file and I want the first and last characters to be trimmed but only if they are equal to a certain character. I'm looking to remove "{" and "}" from a string but ONLY IF THEY ARE THE FIRST AND LAST CHARACTERS RESPECTIVELY.

Input:

```
{Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test}
```

Output:

```
Some_random_data, {more data here}, test
```

Here's the full command I'm using which is able to remove the first one but not the last one.

```
$(head -n 1 "$filePath" | sed s/^{//;s/}$//)
```

Comment: What do you want to do if the first character is `{` but the last character is not `}`, or the first characters is not `{` but the last character is `}`?

Comment: If either one exists, just remove it. If neither exist then there is nothing to remove. Also, } will not appear at the start and { will not appear at the end so we don't have to accommodate for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution worked when I tested it, I only had to escape the `;`.

```
$ echo '{Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test}' | sed s/^{//\;s/}$//
Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

OP's current code and complete output:

```
$ $(head -n 1 file | sed s/^{//;s/}$//)
-bash: s/}$//: No such file or directory
-bash: Some_random_data_here,: command not found
```

Suggestions:

- remove the `$( .... )` wrapper since we don't want to *execute* the results of the `sed` script
- wrap the `sed` script in single quotes so the `;` is treated as part of the `sed` script (and not treated as a `bash` command separator)

Making these changes to OP's current code:

```
$ head -n 1 file | sed 's/^{//;s/}$//'
Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test
```

---

While this will get OP's current code working for *this* particular piece of data it does not actually meet OP's requirement that *both* characters must exist before removing them.  Consider the following examples where one of the bookends is missing:

```
### no leading '{'

$ echo 'Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test}' | sed 's/^{//;s/}$//'
Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test

### no trailing '}'

$ echo '{Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test' | sed 's/^{//;s/}$//'
Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test
```

In both cases the leading `{`, or trailing `}`, is removed even though both characters don't exist.

One `sed` idea using a capture group and a regex that matches on both bookends:

```
### no leading '{'

$ echo 'Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test}' | sed -E 's/^\{(.*)}$/\1/'
Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test}

### no trailing '}'

$ echo '{Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test' | sed -E 's/^\{(.*)}$/\1/'
{Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test

### both bookends present

$ echo '{Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test}' | sed -E 's/^\{(.*)}$/\1/'
Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test
```

Where:

- `-E` - enables extended regex support
- `^\{` - matches start of input (`^`) followed by a `{`; we need to escape the `{` otherwise it's treated as part of the `sed` scripting language, ie, we want it treated as a literal `{`
- `}$` - matches `}` at end of the input (`$`)
- `(.*)` - (first) capture group that matches everything between `^{` and `}$`
- `\1` - reference the contents of the (first) capture group
- in the first 2 examples no characters are removed since we don't get a dual match on `^{` and `}$`
- the 3rd example removes the bookends because we get a successful dual match on `^{` and `}$`

Comment: Apologies, it's either or. Both or just one of them can exist. I was using "and" to indicate that { must be the first and } must be the last, not that both must be present so if it comes in as {data1, {data2}, data3 or data1, {data2}, data3} the output should always be data1, {data2}, data3. I was executing the result because I was storing to a variable but didn't think that was relevant to include, my bad on that. However, thanks for the further explanation it taught me something.

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` verson >= 3.0 and a regex:

```
read line < file;
if [[ "$line" =~ ^\{(.*)\}$ ]]; then
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}";
else
  echo "$line";
fi
```

Output:

```
Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the first line and removing braces can be done with pure POSIX shell (`sh`) code (so it will work with Bash, Dash, and others):

```
read -r line <"$filePath"
line=${line#\{}
line=${line%\}}

printf '%s\n' "$line"
```

If you want to remove braces only when both opening and closing braces are present then this POSIX shell code does it:

```
read -r line <"$filePath"
case $line in
    {*}) line=${line#?}; line=${line%?};;
esac

printf '%s\n' "$line"
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, chaining `sed` expressions with `':'` is fine when using GNU `sed`, but not all `sed` will support it. In that case you can split the substitution expressions with separate `-e` options using numbered backreferences like:

```bash
sed -e 's/^{\(.*\)$/\1/' -e 's/^\(.*\)}$/\1/'
```

or the equivalent beginning/end trim:

```bash
sed -e 's/^{//' -e 's/}$//'
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo '{Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test}' | sed -e 's/^{\(.*\)$/\1/' -e 's/^\(.*\)}$/\1/'
Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test
```

or

```
$ echo 'Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test}' | sed -e 's/^{\(.*\)$/\1/' -e 's/^\(.*\)}$/\1/'
Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test
```

or

```
$ echo '{Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test' | sed -e 's/^{\(.*\)$/\1/' -e 's/^\(.*\)}$/\1/'
Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test
```

or

```
$ echo 'Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test' | sed -e 's/^{\(.*\)$/\1/' -e 's/^\(.*\)}$/\1/'
Some_random_data_here, {more data here}, test
```

Just a caveat to be aware of if you run into an odd system.